# python logger, only error is writing

Tags: linux, logging, python-2.7

I use python 2.7.5
I created a file with configurations for logger:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,api

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file

[logger_api]
handlers=fileapi
qualname=api

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen,fileapi

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=NOTSET
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=complex
level=NOTSET
args=('/var/log/FMV/fmv.log',)

[handler_fileapi]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=5
formatter=complex
level=NOTSET
args=('/var/log/FMV/fmv_api.log',)
```

when i call in my code logger.info and etc:

```
_api_logger = logging.getLogger("api")
_api_logger.info("/index was called")
_api_logger.debug("/index was called")
_api_logger.error("/index was called")
```

in my log file (/var/log/FMV/fmv_api.log) i see following:

```
2013-06-12 01:17:55,599 - api - ERROR - api : 13 - /index was called
```

So only error messages are recorder to log file.
 Why it doesn't write all message to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with adding the following code:

```
[logger_api]
handlers=fileapi
qualname=api
level=DEBUG   <--- Added
```

Answer (score 1):

Logger.setLevel(lvl)
Sets the threshold for this logger to lvl. Logging messages which are less severe than lvl will be ignored. When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

The term ‘delegation to the parent’ means that if a logger has a level of NOTSET, its chain of ancestor loggers is traversed until either an ancestor with a level other than NOTSET is found, or the root is reached.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

Comment: I have set logger level in my config file - level=NOTSET. Why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes i have read it. But a cannot understand it. Why when i set level from code - it works, and when i set level from config file it doesn't work?